# domDocument createElement value does not allow whitespace in php

Tags: php, xml, excel

I want to create an XLSX file using PHP, but it does not allow me to use `creatElement` with whitespace.

For Example, Here is an original XML file :

```
<ID>RC200</ID>

<item_title>Tanker101</item_title>

<price>240 USD</price>
```

Here is what it is supposed to look like:

```
<ID>RC200</ID>

<item title>Tanker101</item title>

<price>240 USD</price>
```

You will see that in `item title`, it should be written with whitespace, but Excel and PHP won't allow that. It said "invalid character error."

Any solution to write Excel file with whitespace allowed?

Comment: i could not find any diff between those two xmls

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#d0e804) have an XML element name with a space in it. The [start tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-stag) would not be invalid XML, but an element `item` with attribute `title`. The end tag is where you're getting the error.